# Pivoting data set twice, by event and by twin

Tags: r

A bit of pivot_wider hell this one. I have a dataset with twins that were measured in three events on a certain psychological scale. I usually can pivot the data set by twins according to their order and family, but not in this case.

- how can I also pivot the twins according to the event?

It is pivoting twice, questions here does not seem to ever have addressed this use case. So given the data:

```r
structure(list(FID = c("A.7325", "A.7325", "A.8638", "A.8638", 
"A.3976", "A.3976", "A.3144", "A.3144", "A.4548", "A.4548", "A.4548", 
"A.1940", "A.1940", "A.1940", "A.3444", "A.3444", "A.5027", "A.5027", 
"A.5027", "A.6918", "A.6918", "A.3445", "A.7324", "A.7324", "A.2133", 
"A.2133", "A.1600", "A.1600", "A.3034", "A.3034", "A.3034", "A.1601", 
"A.1601", "A.3446", "A.3446", "A.3446", "A.7326", "A.7326", "A.2135", 
"A.2135", "A.6178", "A.6178", "A.783", "A.783", "A.8639", "A.8639", 
"A.2134", "A.2134", "A.5921", "A.5921", "A.5921", "A.769", "A.769", 
"A.769", "A.9653", "A.9653", "A.9653", "A.4890", "A.4890", "A.9654", 
"A.9654", "A.428", "A.428", "A.428", "A.3145", "A.3145", "A.770", 
"A.770", "A.7852", "A.7852", "A.7852", "A.1602", "A.1602", "A.8640", 
"A.8640", "A.9971", "A.9971", "A.9971", "A.3447", "A.3447", "A.3447", 
"A.2945", "A.2945", "A.7391", "A.7391", "A.7391", "A.9651", "A.9651", 
"A.9651", "A.6260", "A.6260", "A.6260", "A.6019", "A.6019", "A.6019", 
"A.6919", "A.6919", "A.3449", "A.3449", "A.4549"), zygPi = c("B.NA", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.2", 
"B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.2", "B.2", 
"B.2", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.1", "B.1", 
"B.1", "B.1", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", 
"B.NA", "B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.1", "B.1", "B.1", "B.2", "B.2", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.2", "B.2", 
"B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.1", "B.1", 
"B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.1", "B.1", "B.1", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", 
"B.2", "B.2", "B.2", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA", "B.NA"), 
    eventname = c("C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.2", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", 
    "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", 
    "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", 
    "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", 
    "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", 
    "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.1", 
    "C.3", "C.1", "C.3"), upps_total = c("1.06382978723404", 
    "0.870406189555126", "0.599613152804642", "0.947775628626692", 
    "0.986460348162476", "1.17988394584139", "0.967117988394584", 
    "1.02514506769826", "0.928433268858801", "0.870406189555126", 
    "0.947775628626692", "1.12185686653772", "1.10251450676983", 
    "1.00580270793037", "1.14119922630561", "1.12185686653772", 
    "0.793036750483559", "0.947775628626692", "0.986460348162476", 
    "0.754352030947776", "1.19922630560928", "0.947775628626692", 
    "0.851063829787234", "0.909090909090909", "1.25725338491296", 
    "1.12185686653772", "1.1605415860735", "1.23791102514507", 
    "0.793036750483559", "1.00580270793037", "0.870406189555126", 
    "1.06382978723404", "0.851063829787234", "0.831721470019342", 
    "0.986460348162476", "1.08317214700193", "1.17988394584139", 
    "1.08317214700193", "1.29593810444874", "1.04448742746615", 
    "1.1605415860735", "0.831721470019342", "0.967117988394584", 
    "1.02514506769826", "1.1605415860735", "1.14119922630561", 
    "1.10251450676983", "0.928433268858801", "1.1605415860735", 
    "1.00580270793037", "0.909090909090909", "1.19922630560928", 
    "1.06382978723404", "1.08317214700193", "0.967117988394584", 
    "1.14119922630561", "1.06382978723404", "1.06382978723404", 
    "1.06382978723404", "0.889748549323017", "0.889748549323017", 
    "0.889748549323017", "0.870406189555126", "1.10251450676983", 
    "0.889748549323017", "0.889748549323017", "1.14119922630561", 
    "1.00580270793037", "0.909090909090909", "0.928433268858801", 
    "0.851063829787234", "1.04448742746615", "0.831721470019342", 
    "1.02514506769826", "0.909090909090909", "0.928433268858801", 
    "0.928433268858801", "1.00580270793037", "0.889748549323017", 
    "0.793036750483559", "0.967117988394584", "0.793036750483559", 
    "0.928433268858801", "0.851063829787234", "0.831721470019342", 
    "0.793036750483559", "1.10251450676983", "0.986460348162476", 
    "1.08317214700193", "0.909090909090909", "1.21856866537718", 
    "1.17988394584139", "1.02514506769826", "0.967117988394584", 
    "1.02514506769826", "1.14119922630561", "1.06382978723404", 
    "1.25725338491296", "1.17988394584139", "0.909090909090909"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

and given the MWE:

```r
mwe %>%
  group_by(FID, zygPi) %>%
  mutate(TID = factor(rank(FID, ties.method = "first"))) %>%
  filter(TID %in% c(1, 2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(FID) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(TID), names_prefix = "T",
    values_from = c("upps_total")
  )
```

I end up with:

```r
# A tibble: 84 × 5
# Groups:   FID [43]
   FID    zygPi eventname T1                T2               
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>             <chr>            
 1 A.7325 B.NA  C.3       1.06382978723404  NA               
 2 A.7325 B.NA  C.1       NA                0.870406189555126
 3 A.8638 B.NA  C.3       0.599613152804642 NA               
 4 A.8638 B.NA  C.1       NA                0.947775628626692
 5 A.3976 B.NA  C.3       0.986460348162476 NA               
 6 A.3976 B.NA  C.2       NA                1.17988394584139 
 7 A.3144 B.NA  C.3       0.967117988394584 NA               
 8 A.3144 B.NA  C.1       NA                1.02514506769826 
 9 A.4548 B.2   C.3       0.928433268858801 NA               
10 A.4548 B.2   C.1       NA                0.870406189555126
# ℹ 74 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Notable is that in this case it is not properly aligning the twins by family, so T1 and T2 must stay in the same row. And finally, how can I further pivot by eventname (a factor w 3 levels))?

Comment: So what is the desired output for this sample input? Please provide that in the question as well so possible answers can be tested and verified.